# Learning complex analysis through problem solving

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

I am looking for a problem book on complex analysis with solutions that covers/teaches basic and advanced topics of complex analysis (the same topics covered in a standard textbook like Ahlfors with some geometric flavor and more advanced topics on special functions, monodromy, etc) through problem solving. Well, it doesn't necessary need to be a problem book per se, but even if it's not, I still want it to have enough challenging problems that the reader can acquire problem solving techniques in complex analysis through them (with the solutions or hints).

Video lectures that are problem-solving oriented will be highly appreciated too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure it has enough problem solving for you but it is a must read for a great insight to complex analysis: https://books.google.it/books/about/Visual_Complex_Analysis.html?id=ogz5FjmiqlQC&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 0):

Though I do not know your level, following are the my favorites:

[Brown-Churchill-Complex Variables and Application](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjaqbvJ-OzLAhUmMJoKHZ2vCegQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ucsb.edu%2F~wei%2Fteach%2F122%2FBrown-Churchill-Complex%2520Variables%2520and%2520Application%25208th%2520edition.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGn3NuG1qDNFcYDBqs4UjfNZQ9XBQ),

[Complex Analysis Joseph Bak and Donald J. Newmann](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiU1ZjR-ezLAhWCApoKHc9QCGkQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fbook%2F10.1007%252F978-1-4419-7288-0&usg=AFQjCNH83XUjyK1lrCtjDfebrXbJz6CAig) .

Not only problems, but also they give nice explanations about complicated concepts in complex analysis.